# How can I make VS Code check for errors when referencing properties of JSON imported into JS?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

I am working on JS files, I have imported the JSON file which contains JSON objects,
If there is some typing mistake while using the key of an object it does not give any (error)red squiggly.
So is there any vs code extension present for it which can check it and show me an error?

Comment: if the to load file is set with a command line argument, how do you suspect the JavaScript Language server to know which keys are valid. It is a static code analyzer.

Comment: What JSON extension are you using?  There are many.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour here is controlled by the builtin TypeScript extension of VS Code, which is powered by TypeScript itself.

For JS files, I don't know about getting VS Code to treat it as as problem when you reference a property that doesn't exist in an imported JSON file (I think that might be by design for the JS support in VS Code), but it at least does provide some suggestions (autocompletion) for properties that *do* exist. It does this both when you use EMCAScript and RequireJS-style imports (Ex. `import * as j from "./test.json";`, `import j from "./test.json";`, `import j from "./test.json" assert { type: "json" };` and `const j = require("./test.json");`). There are limitations with that, which are touched upon in this issue ticket: [import ConstJson from './config.json' as const; #32063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063).

For TS files, it will treat accesses to properties that don't exist as problems.